# Is there a Visual Studio color scheme similar to Webmatrix?

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme, webmatrix

Webmatrix has a clean color scheme. Is there a similar one for Visual Studio?

Comment: You should upvote both of these answers and mark one as accepted. They both provide the tools to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Webmatrix color scheme for visual studio.](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/webmatrix-1)

Comment: Well, this is the one that I myself created. But technically, you deserve the point :)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Aero theme for VS2010 is the closest I was able to get using the themes that are built into the Theme plug-in. Of course you could start there and customize further to get even closer.

For anyone looking for the theme editor, it can be found at: [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)